# char(17) vs varchar(17) for a latin type declaration

Tags: mysql, char, varchar

I have a database table that stores images. The acceptable types are jpg/png/gif/ and the name is always going to have 13 characters.

In other words, the filename length is always going to be 17 characters long (13 for the name + the ‘.’ + the extension).

For all that I’ve read in here, I believe that I should declare it as a char because it takes less space.

Here’s my 2 questions:

- Assuming that my filename is always going to be latin1 type, not
  utf8, is it true that a char(17) takes less bytes then a varchar(17)?
- If yes, how many? (i’m actually not sure how to calculate the bytes in a char and varchar)

Thanks

Comment: RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html  You can only assume a worst-case maximum for bytes in a char/varchar when dealing with utf-8, because a single utf-8 character could potentially be 2-4 bytes at least, and possibly longer

Comment: so if i've read your link correctly, it's 17 bytes for the char and 18 bytes for the varchar (assuming that they are latin1 type) and therefore i should use char(17) in my table... is that correct?

Comment: yes. the length of a char field is explicitly the same as its specified length. if you insert less than that into the field, the DB will pad out the "missing" characters so the inserted size matches the char field's actual size. varchar must store how long the inserted data is, so there's the overhead of storing that size. regardless of whether you insert exactly the field's length, or less.

Comment: talk about making sure you declare the column correctly from to get go. I mean 20 wrong declarations that hold 25 000 records and that's an extra 5mb in your database size... and that's only for one type... thanks @MarcB